# TinyMCE removing html tags on init

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I try to paste HTML code. I use tinymce code plugin. After save it's OK.

The source code: `<p><code>&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;test&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</code></p>`
Displayed on page: `<html><body>test</body></html>`

When I edit it again, after opening all html code is missing: `<p><code>test</code></p>`

I'm using version 4.5.

Answer (score 1):

I can load your content into TinyMCE and it maintains all the correct elements:

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/keiaab

That fiddle works with TinyMCE 4, 5, and 6.

Please note that TinyMCE 4 is not a currently supported or maintained TinyMCE version.  At present the supported versions are TinyMCE 5 and TinyMCE 6.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with the newest version

Comment: I have tested it on newest version of TinyMCE and it's the same. After first save to database it's ok but when I edit it again the html code is missing. It's not the problem with TinyMCE's version.

Answer (score 0):

It is not Tinymce problem concentrate on textarea!

when you load html entities from DB inside texarea,the textarea converts them to html

for example:

```html
 &lt;meta charset="UTF-8"&gt;
```

to

```html
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
```

to solve this problem we use htmlentities function in PHP:

```html
 print "<textarea>". htmlentities($content) ."</textarea>";
```